# Fixed Term Work - No longer a good fit?

Tags: professionalism, internship, motivation

What are the concerns (ethical and other) should one be concerned with when motivation at a temporary position is threatened due to culture clashes or lack of quality work assignments?

**Scenario:**

Consider being in a fixed term contract where the term is either short, or ending shortly (3-6 months), how does one go about receiving work that is applicable, "fun", and the most beneficial to the rest of the team?

In full time employment, one should try to improve group practices (including becoming more involved in how work is assigned) over the long term, or actively looking for different employment.

However, this dynamic changes when working on a fixed term.

Some methods are applicable to both (talking to manager, boy scout principle, etc). Assuming these methods have already been used, is it worth escalating concerns further?

**Summation:**

How do you professionally "ride out" a contract that doesn't have any work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. As an employer I would only hire someone on a short, fixed term if I had work that needed doing that I did not want to give to someone on my team because I did not believe they would enjoy or learn from it (unless we were truly swamped with nothing but a huge pile of interesting work). The company gains nothing from giving enjoyable work that involves obvious personal growth to a person who will be gone in a matter of months. If you don't like that, then you need to seek permanent employment so that somebody else will have a reason to invest in you long term.

Comment: For co-op students that may have short-term placements, there can be something to be said for seeing how good is the fit and possibly rotating the person around even though they may only be working in 4 month terms with gaps to go back to school.

Comment: You speak in such vague generalities that I have no idea what you are talking about. And since your question is built on what you are saying, I don't have a clue what your question is either, even after three consecutive re-readings of your post. I am voting to close your question as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the summary is a different question than the one you seemed to be asking.

If they really don't have any work for you, you may be still be valuable to them as "on call" staff. I grant that being "gainfully underemployed" is less fun than folks think it might be, but it beats being unemployed.

So what do you do about it? The possibilities I can think of offhand would be:

!) Gently remind them (repeatedly if necessary, and by going to co-workers if management is disorganized)  that since they're paying you they might want to actually use you. Look for things that your employer needs done that they don't *realize* they need done, and offer to assist with those. This is especially appropriate if they supposedly hired you to advise them rather than just to do a specific task.

2) Ask them if they want to cancel the contract early so you can move on to something else (if you have something better lined up) or at least switch to a situation where they have you on call but you can take on other work as well

3) like (1), but invest the time they're not using in improving your skills so you can land better contracts and/or higher-paying contracts

Even non-term-employees occasionally have to actively go looking for stuff that is worth doing. Learn to self-start... and accept that this is part of the nature of term employment. The alternative is to contract to do a specific job, term not to exceed whatever... and to be more active in having the next contract(s) lined up so you can move over when you're freed. That's easier if you have skills that let you price yourself as a consultant rather than as a temp.